# Bringing the top gradient on text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have this circle gradient in the top right corner of this webpage but I actually want this to come over the image.

Currently, I have this:

[image]

Whereas, I want this to be like here:

[image]

Here is my css code for the top-right-gradient:

```css
.top-right-gradient{
    position: absolute;
    top: -40%;
    right: -14%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#ee9ca7, #ec4357);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make sure your image is a PNG file with a transparant background, or an SVG file without a background fill.

Comment: Oh yes! It worked once I made the image background transparent. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.